# StringTokenizer error: NoSuchelementException after tokenized line finishes

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

When I feed the tokenizer a line from my keyboard it has no problem. However,
I'm trying to feed my input though a file line with a name that has a space between the two words. That's when I get the NoSuchelementException error. I'm not sure if I need to close the file? But the file has more information that needs to be read. Thank you for taking the time to read my question :)

Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
line = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);
StringTokenizer lineTok = new StringTokenizer(line);
first = (String) lineTok.nextToken();
last = (String) lineTok.nextToken();
```

Comment: @Leviand sc is Scanner class object.

Comment: try using `if (lineTok.hasMoreElements())` before calling `lineTok.nextToken();`

Comment: @SABER-FICTIONALCHARACTER I was not aware of that method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the following one will print all the words from the line.

```
package tryouts;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringTokenizerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(
                "/usr/projects/tryouts/src/tryouts/test.txt"));
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        StringTokenizer lineTok = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (lineTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(lineTok.nextToken());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

```
package tryouts;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringTokenizerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/usr/projects/tryouts/src/tryouts/test.txt"));
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        StringTokenizer lineTok = new StringTokenizer(line);
        String first = (String) lineTok.nextToken();
        System.out.println(first);
        String last = (String) lineTok.nextToken();
        System.out.println(last);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Create a file named "test.txt" in the folder "/usr/projects/tryouts/src/tryouts/" with a single line content as "first second third fourth" and it prints first and second.

Comment: Why did you write 2 answers? This is highly confusing

Comment: It is better for future readers and for the op if you put them into one post and it is also highly confusing as it is not a common practice here ;)